# Laravel-mix used in project, everything builds, but in browser it doesn't work

Tags: node.js, npm, vuex, yarnpkg

I have a project from other developer and I try to add to it few components. But I still cannot run it.

I've installed all dependences using `yarn install`, than I've executed `npm run dev` and when I execute `npm run hot`, there aren't any error in console on my localhost:8081, I see clear white screen.

Can you help me please, give me an idea where to look for a problem? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It was amazing stupid error. I have XAMPP installed on my PC and Tomcat works on port 8080, so `npm run hot` started server on 8081, but additional javascripts was loaded from 8080. ...

It wasn't only one reason, I don't remember how it becames to show me those js-files. First, they wasn't called from script any time.